# How to create bricks(divs) dynamically to make brickwall like layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a a brick wall like layout with divs as bricks and created dynamically with JavaScript. The length of the brick should be according to the image or text represent the brick. I may not be able to explain well in words so I'm attaching an image so everybody can understand that what I am trying to do. 
Many Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Here is something I made that you can look at since it is somewhat similar to what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/www139/e3nzt3up/

Comment: I should say very well done. Can you please add anything that I want to do. Every brick should be created by with the help of a dialog box which serves as an input for image or text and that text or image will be brick iteself and will have length according to the text/image.

Comment: I will write an answer but you should know that Stackoverflow is a place for people trying to understand and find solutions for things they don't understand, not a place for asking people to program for you. You might get better results by rephrasing this question like "how do I know how many bricks to place within a specific space" or something like that :)

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing things up for me.

Comment: Just letting you know because people here think that way. Not necessarily me but others.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @knight If Ki Jey answered your question, there is no reason to write an answer since I would have written something just like he/she did.

Answer (score 3):

You need `display: inline-block` to prevent each `<div>` to take a full line, a `background-color`, and some `margin` if you need this little whitespace between the bricks. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mouradif/6NYJX/4/) I even put a little padding for style.

Comment: Thanks www139, I was looking at your animatedTiles fiddle right now it's beautiful :D

Comment: Jey Thank you, glad you like it :)